# Update User Info with user id in session

Tags: php, mysql, session, user-controls, profile

I have a project, where users can edit their own profile.
I currently have a login/register page. Now its time for a user-edit page.
The site works with **sessions** so, whenever they come back they see myprofile in the navbar.

I've tested everything in PHP, to update the account.

I currently have 2 files where the update-profile scripts works with.

`1 is the profile.php, the other in includes/update.inc.php`

In `includes/login.inc.php` I have already assigned a session.

```
          if ($pwdCheck == false) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpassword");
        exit();
      }
      else if ($pwdCheck == true) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
        $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];

        header("Location: ../index.php?logging=succes");
        exit();
```

So yeah that was from the **includes/login.inc.php**.

Now when u go to your profile it checks `if $_SESSION['userId'] == true.`

Now the following:

This is my profile.php

```
    <?php
     require "header.php";
      require "includes/dbh.inc.php";
         $sessionkk = $_SESSION['userId'];
         error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

      $query = "SELECT idUsers, uidUsers, emailUsers,pwdUsers,Voornaam,Tussenvoegsel,Achternaam,Schooljaar,School,Opleiding,Niveau,Recht,Taal 
 , 
 printerA,printerB,printerC FROM users WHERE idUsers = '$sessionkk'";
   $result = $conn->query($query) or die($conn->error);

   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $id = $row['idUsers'];
   $username = $row['uidUsers'];
   $email = $row['emailUsers'];
   $password = $row['pwdUsers'];
   $voornaam = $row['Voornaam'];
   $tussenvoegsel = $row['Tussenvoegsel'];
   $achternaam = $row['Achternaam'];
   $Schooljaar = $row['Schooljaar'];
   $School = $row['School'];
   $Opleiding = $row['Opleiding'];
   $niveau = $row['Niveau'];
   $Taal = $row['Taal'];
   $printera = $row['printerA'];
   $printerb = $row['printerB'];
   $printerc = $row['printerC'];

}
}





?>

  <div class="adminform">
      <h2>gegevens aanpassen</h2><br/>
          <form action="includes/update.inc.php" method="POST">
              <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" 
value=" 
<?php if(isset($_GET['username'])){echo $_GET['username'];}?>"><br/><br/>
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" value="<?php 
if(isset($_GET['email'])){echo $_GET['email'];}?>"><br/><br/>
          <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Schooljaar" value="<?php 
if(isset($_GET['Schooljaar'])){echo $_GET['Schooljaar'];}?>"><br/><br/>
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" value="<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['School'])){echo $_GET['School'];}?>"><br/><br/>
          <button type="submit" name="adminupdate">Aanpassen</button>
      </form>
      <?php
        echo "" . $id;

       ?>
  </div>
 <?php

 ?>
```

Here i conclude everything. The formname etc etc.

You can also see how i make a `$sessionkk = $_SESSION['userId'];`

The $sessionkk works with the

Here is the include/update.inc.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
       require "dbh.inc.php";


    if(isset($_POST['adminupdate'])){

     $sql = "UPDATE users SET  uidUsers= '?', emailUsers = '?', Schooljaar = 
 '?', 
     School = '?' WHERE idUsers = '.$sessionkk.'";
                 $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                 if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
                       header("Location: ../profile.php?error=sqlerror");
                      exit();
                } else{
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $username, $email, 
          $Schooljaar, $School);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                    header("Location: ../profile.php?update=succes");
                    exit();
                }
              }
     ?>
```

I tried the $sql query with just the ID from the database so it would be like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET  uidUsers= '?', emailUsers = '?', Schooljaar = '?', 
School = '?' WHERE idUsers = '4'";
```

and this would work.
But i want to grab the id from the user who is logged in.
Sorry that the code is so messy, i dont know how to upload code correctly here.

Thank you

Comment: i see SQL injections problems and normalisation problems in your current code the columns `printerA,printerB,printerC` are good candidates for normalisation

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you for answering, I will try to fix those problems. Still have my query error.

Comment: Your didn't mention the in question you have a query error? What is the error?

Comment: @RaymondNijland sometimes it doesnt even give me an error, it goes straight to my url localhost/accmng/profile.php?succes. And when i change the code it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: You declared **$sessionkk** in profile.php, but not in update.inc.php, that's why your code is failing. Just declare $sessionkk in your second file and you should be fine

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb Doesnt work.